# Parametric plot of data from NDSolve

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I have been trying to plot the solution of a set of differential equations solved used `NDSolve`. Now, in one of the cases, I have the find a parametric plot of the square of the absolutes between the solution `a1[t]` with `a1'[t]`. I tried to do it as the documentation of `NDSolve` suggested and with many other ways given on Mathematica StackExchange, but was unable to get the plot.

I also noticed that, when I tried to make a table of values from `a1'[t]` at different values of `t`, it failed as well. This again did not happen in the example given in the documentation. Please help me understand what mistakes I have made in my program.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

w0 = 190*10^12;
wm = 23.4*2*Pi*10^6;
gama = 2*Pi*10^6;
gama2 = 0.8*gama;
gama1 = gama;
g0 = 7.4*10^-5*gama;
gamam = 0.038*2*Pi*gama;
del1 = wm;
J = gama;

driv = 0.5*gama;

eqns = 
 {a1'[t] == (-I*(del1 - Sqrt[2]*g0*x[t]) - gama1/(2))*a1[t] + I*J*a2[t] + driv,
  a2'[t] == (-I*del1 + gama2/(2))*a2[t] + I*J*a1[t], 
  p'[t] == -gamam/2*p[t] - wm*x[t] + Sqrt[2]*g0*Abs[a1[t]]^2,
  x'[t] == wm*p[t], 
  x[0] == 0, a1[0] == 0, a2[0] == 0, p[0] == 0};

s = NDSolve[eqns, {a1[t], a2[t], x[t], p[t]}, {t, 0, 0.00001}, MaxSteps -> ∞]

ParametricPlot[
  Evaluate[{Abs[a1'[t]]^2, Abs[a1[t]]^2} /. s], {t, 0.000008, 0.000009}, 
  PlotRange -> Automatic]
```

I would be very grateful if you could tell me my mistake in this program.

Comment: Ask NDSolve for pure functions if you want to generate derivative later:  `s = NDSolve[eqns, {a1, a2, x, p}, {t, 0, 0.00001}, 
  MaxSteps -> \[Infinity]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NDSolveValue` would allow you to get the requested expressions directly:

```
sValue = NDSolveValue[eqns, {Abs[a1'[t]]^2, Abs[a1[t]]^2}, {t, 0, 0.00001}];

ParametricPlot[
  sValue, {t, 0.000008, 0.000009},
  PlotRange -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> 0.5
]
```

[image: parametric plot]